# Spring Boot creating a JSON attribute as ArrayList of String not working

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot, jackson

So I am creating a get request for an API (Which expect string separated by commas)that is calling another API and I am not able to understand what it is missing.The external API is expecting data like below which is working in Postman if I send same data.

```
{
  "data":["appName1","appName2"]
}
```

I am creating a DTO and using this Strings to create an ArrayList of String. I have quite experience of working but this scenario is giving me error.

While evaluating I saw list is like [APP_NAME1,APP_NAME2] as it is missing string quotation ".

Anyone can help me?

Comment: show the code with error messages, and also the postman body request

Comment: {
  "data":["appName1","appName2"]
} THis is postman request and it is working. the above statement i just missing " in list

Comment: How do you serialise `List` to `JSON`?

Comment: So your question is you cannot deserialize the request JSON string to your DTO as expected, right?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
String data = "{" + "data : [ " + appName1 + " ," + appName2 + "]" + "}";
```

Hope useful for you

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to convert ypur objects to JSON are Gson or Jackson libraries.
You should add dependencies to your maven or gradle and just use it.
Example for Gson:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = gson.toJson(yourObject);
```

Example for Jackson:

```
ObjectWriter ow = new ObjectMapper().writer().withDefaultPrettyPrinter();
String json = ow.writeValueAsString(yourObject);
```